# Support multiple displays from a web application

Tags: asp.net, multiple-monitors

I have a customer requirement where they would like to have different windows of a web application on 2 different displays (monitors): data lookup and entry on one screen and a document viewer on the other. The document viewer will be Flash or Silverlight based and loaded in a webpage. The app will be at least partially based on SharePoint. There is a need for communication between the two windows: when for instance a new task is clicked in the "data" view, the accompanying document needs to be opened in the other one.

The difficulties as far as I can determine:

- Opening the two windows from within a web app
- Actively position the windows on the 2 displays
- communication between the two windows
- as robust a solution as possible from a user perspective (e.g., re-opening a closed window, tracking changes between them, etc.)

I am looking for pointers in getting this done. I understand that I can launch the second window from Javascript, but that does not give me a lot of control over it. This solution will run in a closed, controlled environment, so limiting the solution to a specific browser (preferably IE8+) or the need to install additional software/components is no problem.

Comment: Talk about weird requirements... have a +1  :)

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would implement this with silverlight and asp.net mvc.

create a state object which describes the state of the 2 windows, this can be consumed and updated by both the silverlight app via web services, and the mvc app via javascript, postbacks or web services.

Comment: That is actually something I had not thought of; would you then have both windows poll the server periodically? Do you have additional suggestions to position the windows on the 2 physical displays?

Comment: polling is an option, although it will depend on the requirements. you can set up duplex communication with silverlight ria services, or you could wait for user action. what will fit your requirements?